# Query mongodb collection into nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a model called List.js that looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(mongoose, models) {
    var collection = 'List',
        Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var schema = new Schema({
        promotor: String,
        nombre_promotor: String,
        cod_evento: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Evento'},
        lista: [{
            nombre: String,
            cod_usuario_lider: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Usuario'
            }, 
            usuarios_agregados: [{ 
                cod_usuario: {
                    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'Usuario'
                },
                nombre: String,
                fbid: String,
                tipo_usuario: Number
            }]
        }]
    });
    this.model = mongoose.model(collection, schema);
    return this;
}
```

Im trying to find the documents that match with cod_usuario_lider in the field "lista" and the ones that match with "cod_usuario" in  "usuarios_agregados" inside "lista". The first part of the query returns the matched documents, but the second part doesnt return nothing. Anyone knows the proper way to do that query?

```
var codigo_buscar=req.body.codigo_buscar;
 models.List.find({
                    $or: [{
                        lista: {
                            $elemMatch: {
                                cod_usuario_lider: codigo_buscar
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        usuarios_agregados: {
                            $elemMatch: {
                                cod_usuario: codigo_buscar
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                })
.exec(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The first part of the query returns the matched documents, but the second part doesnt return nothing. Anyone knows the proper way to do that query?

Answer (score 0):

From your document, it looks like usuarios_agregados is an attribute to lista. In that case you have to query as below:

```
var codigo_buscar=req.body.codigo_buscar;
 models.List.find({
                    $or: [{
                        lista: {
                            $elemMatch: {
                                cod_usuario_lider: codigo_buscar
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        lista.usuarios_agregados: {
                            $elemMatch: {
                                cod_usuario: codigo_buscar
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                })
.exec(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```